# Making a Bibtex Reference Page WITHOUT citing stuff

Tags: bibtex

OK Here is my situation, I'm told to use `bibtex` for all my references/biblography needs.

I made a `.bib` file, put a few entries in for testing, and put the two lines of code I need in the main `.tex` file.

```
\bibliography{bibtex}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

So, the catch is, the reference list is completely empty UNLESS, I have cited them once at any point of my passages - I guess because they are numbered automatically? (the compile told me that it can't find any cite command in `aux` and, it is considered an error)

I already have all the entries I want to put in a MS Word file, so I just want them to copy over and show up nicely as a list of References.

Is this possible without citing?
Because quite franky, I don't even know when and where I ever used them ... and I don't want to type `\cite` for another 50 times. :(

Can someone tell me what I should tell the compile to just show what is on the document (like any other list) and not care about whether I have cited it or not?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I think the `\nocite` command is what you need, but I don't see what “MS Word” is doing here. o( o_o )o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following MWE you can see how to display not cited bib entrys in your bibliography.  The command you need to us is simply `\nocite{*}`.  That means that all (`*`) not cited bib entrys are shown in the bibliography too.

With the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
article{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
@article{Ross2006,
  title     = {Treating the right patient at the right time: 
               access to heart failure care},
  author    = {Ross, H and Howlett, J and Arnold, J Malcolm O and 
               Liu, P and O’Neill, BJ and Brophy, JM and Simpson, CS and 
               Sholdice, MM and Knudtson, M and Ross, DB and others},
  journal   = {Canadian journal of Cardiology},
  volume    = {22},
  number    = {9},
  pages     = {749--754},
  year      = {2006},
  publisher = {Elsevier},
}
@article{Heidenreich2013,
  title     = {Forecasting the impact of heart failure in the 
               United States a policy statement from the American Heart Association},
  author    = {Heidenreich, Paul A and Albert, Nancy M and 
               Allen, Larry A and Bluemke, David A and Butler, Javed and 
               Fonarow, Gregg C and Ikonomidis, John S and Khavjou, Olga 
               and Konstam, Marvin A and Maddox, Thomas M and others},
  journal   = {Circulation: Heart Failure},
  volume    = {6},
  number    = {3},
  pages     = {606--619},
  year      = {2013},
  publisher = {Am Heart Assoc},
}
@book{mschinLearning,
  author    = {Tom M. Mitchell}, 
  title     = {Machine learning},
  publisher = {Mac Gew Hill},
  year      = 1997,
  volume    = 4,
  series    = 10,
  address   = {The address},
  edition   = 3,
  month     = 7,
  note      = {An optional note},
  isbn      = {0071154671},
}
@misc{mozart:KV183,
  author  = {Mozart, Wolfgang Amadeus},
  title   = {Sinfonie g-Moll},
  year    = {1773},
  address = {Salzburg},
  note    = {New K{\"o}chelverzeichnis Nr. 183, old version Nr. 25; 
             Erster Satz: Allegro con brio, Zweiter Satz: Andante, 
             Dritter Satz: Menuetto, Vierter Satz: Allegro},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys <===================================
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname} % <====== use bib file created with filecontents

\end{document}
```

you get the wanted result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: We seem to have given identical answers at exactly the same time. I've deleted mine. You don't need `hyperref` in your example though.